# Backend Data not filtering correctly on frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, strapi

Currently I'm using React as my frontend and Strapi as my CMS. I'm trying to filter my data according to a Type and a limit. What I am using to achieve this is:  `http://localhost:1337/citizenships?_limit=5&&CitizenshipType=Europe` which gives me the correct output when I place it just to look at my JSON data. But in my frontend it shows all the data including other CitizenshipTypes.

My current code:

```
export default function Citizenship({ items }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {items &&
          items.map((item) => (
            <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>
              <div class="citizen-item" key={item.id}>
                <div className="container6">
                  <img
                    src={`http://localhost:1337${item.Thumbnail.url}`}
                  />
                  <div>
                    {item.Title}
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    Access to {item.Countries} countries
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <button class="findButton">FIND OUT MORE</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:1337/citizenships?_limit=5&&CitizenshipType=Europe"
  );
  const items = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { items },
  };
}
```

Response with `http://localhost:1337/citizenships?_limit=5`

[image]

Response with `http://localhost:1337/citizenships?_limit=5&&CitizenshipType=Europe`

[image]

Comment: Can you paste a sample object from the API response?

Comment: @tdranv I have updated the question with my responses

Comment: I don't see a problem. Could it be that you have two `&`s in your path?

Comment: No that isnt it